# Getting the values of Default Attribute "Description" in Autodesk Construction Cloud with Forge

Tags: attributes, autodesk-forge, autodesk, acc

We are trying to get the values of Default Attribute "Description"  in Autodesk Construction Cloud with Forge but we can't read it in Forge.
We are getting the values of all the Default Attributes and the Custom Attributes except the attribute that named "Description".

Any good ideas for how we can get that?

We tried with
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/document-management-custom-attribute-definitions-GET/
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/cost-properties-GET/

FDM-3124

Comment: Can you share an image of the "Description" Attribute you are looking for. As of now I do not see any on the UI. That will help me find more about it.

Answer (score 0):

We have an enhancement request to address this data extraction of the "Description" Attribute. For record please keep this number that you can use for reference in the future - FDM-3124